# Selecting latest consecutive records that match a condition with PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am looking for a PostgreSQL query to find the latest consecutive records that match a condition. Let me explain it better with an example:

```
|  ID  |  HEATING STATE  |  DATE       |
| ---- | --------------- |  ---------- |
|  1   |  ON             |  2018-02-19 |
|  2   |  ON             |  2018-02-20 |
|  3   |  OFF            |  2018-02-20 |
|  4   |  OFF            |  2018-02-21 |
|  5   |  ON             |  2018-02-21 |
|  6   |  OFF            |  2018-02-21 |
|  7   |  ON             |  2018-02-22 |
|  8   |  ON             |  2018-02-22 |
|  9   |  ON             |  2018-02-22 |
| 10   |  ON             |  2018-02-23 |
```

I need to find all the recent consecutive records with date >= 2018-02-20 and heating_state ON, i.e. the ones with ID 7, 8, 9, 10. My main issue is with the fact that they must be *consecutive*.

For further clarification, if needed:

- ID 1 is excluded because older than 2018-02-20
- ID 2 is excluded because followed by ID 3 which has heating state OFF
- ID 3 is excluded because it has heating state OFF
- ID 4 is excluded because it is followed by ID 5, which has heating OFF
- ID 5 is excluded because it has heating state OFF
- ID 6 is excluded because it has heating state OFF

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this is best solved using windows functions and a filtered aggregate.

For each row, add the number of later rows that have `state = 'OFF'`, then use only the rows where that count is 0.

You need a subquery because you cannot use a window function result in the `WHERE` condition (`WHERE` is evaluated before window functions).

```
SELECT id, state, date
FROM (SELECT id, state, date,
             count(*) FILTER (WHERE state = 'OFF')
                OVER (ORDER BY date DESC, state DESC) AS later_off_count
      FROM tab) q
WHERE later_off_count = 0;

 id | state |    date    
----+-------+------------
 10 | ON    | 2018-02-23
  9 | ON    | 2018-02-22
  8 | ON    | 2018-02-22
  7 | ON    | 2018-02-22
(4 rows)
```

Comment: Thanks for the submission, but when changing the dataset so that ID 6 has the same data as the following rows then the query does not return any results, see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/d0d71/1

Comment: The behavior in that case is undefined, because there is no clear way to order the rows in that case. Can you specify that?

Comment: Ok, I added a tie breaker such that *only later* `'OFF'` entries block a row from being output. Is that what you want?

Comment: It fails again with a different dataset: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/9c2bc/4 but after all this is irrelevant: I can use a proper timestamp instead of the date for ordering. Thanks!

Comment: I'd say that it does not fail, but that your data don't allow better ordering. Anyway, using a timestamp to get a clear ordering is certainly the correct way to go.

Answer (score 4):

Use the `LEAD` function with  a `CASE` expression.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/f5552/11)

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT id, 
       heating_state, 
       dt 
FROM   (SELECT t.*, 
               CASE 
                 WHEN dt >= timestamp '2018-02-20' 
                      AND heating_state = 'ON' 
                      AND LEAD(heating_state, 1, heating_state) 
                            OVER ( 
                                  ORDER BY dt ) = 'ON' THEN 1 
                 ELSE 0 
               END on_state 
        FROM   t) s 
WHERE  on_state = 1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/f5552/11/0)**:

```
| id | heating_state |                   dt |
|----|---------------|----------------------|
|  7 |            ON | 2018-02-22T00:00:00Z |
|  8 |            ON | 2018-02-22T00:00:00Z |
|  9 |            ON | 2018-02-22T00:00:00Z |
| 10 |            ON | 2018-02-23T00:00:00Z |
```

Comment: I don't think that this solution is correct. If I understand the question correctly, it wants all `ON` rows where there is no later `OFF` row. it just happens to work in this example because there are no two consecutive `ON` rows earlier on.

Comment: @Laurenz Albe : I know. There are too many things to clarify here...I'm waiting for the op to comment..they better do it before I go to sleep..I will be eager to learn from your answer though..

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe that's right, the query doesn't have the behaviour I expect when I tweak the data and add 2 consecutive `ON` before one OFF: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/0b464/1

Comment: @spaghetticode : You must first decide what exactly you want to see the output for various scenarios and clarify that in the question.